# How to add an import statement in a Go wrapper generated by SWIG

Tags: go, swig

I have a wrapper generated by `SWIG` for the `Go` language. In this wrapper, I inserted some `Go` code that needs the package `reflect`. Consequently, I need to add the line `import "reflect"` in this wrapper. Is there an example that illustrates how to do this in `SWIG`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is in [section 23.4.10](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Go.html) *Adding additional go code* namely the part about

> If you need to import other go packages, you can do this with %go_import. For example...

```
%go_import("fmt", _ "unusedPackage", rp "renamed/package")

%insert(go_wrapper) %{

func foo() {
  fmt.Println("Some string:", rp.GetString())
}

// Importing the same package twice is permitted,
// Go code will be generated with only the first instance of the import.
%go_import("fmt")

%insert(go_wrapper) %{

func bar() {
  fmt.Println("Hello world!")
}

%}
```